# How to return value when calling a method from another method in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, return

Iam calling a method from another method in the same class.I used to return value from the second method.but whenever am calling that function from first method,it prints the value that am returning from the second method,and it stops execution.Anyone please help me.

first method:

```
public function firstMethod(){
      $this->secondMethod();
      dd('ok');
}
```

second method:

```
public function secondMethod(){
      return 'true';
}
```

when the execution begin..,it prints **'true'**.Help please....thanks in advance :).

Comment: What do you want to do with the return value?

Comment: based on the returned value i need to continue my first method

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you need to continue after checking the returned value, then you can do this:

```
public function firstMethod(){
    if (!$this->secondMethod()) return; // ends function and returns execution

    dd('ok'); // executed if secondMethod() returns true
}
```